# Google Cloud Composer using google-cloud-bigquery python client library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-python

I'm trying to run a DAG in Google Cloud Composer in which the first component is to use a http GET request to call an API and then use the python-client library to insert the json into a BigQuery table.  I am trying to run this function: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows_json.html

```
import requests
import datetime
import ast
import numpy as np
from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator
from airflow.operators import python_operator
import google.cloud.bigquery as bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project = 'is-flagship-data-api-sand')
dataset_id = 'Mobile_Data_Test'
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('sample_wed')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)

def get_localytics_data():
    profiles_requests_command = "https://%s:%s@api.localytics.com/v1/exports/profiles/%d/profile"%(api_key,api_secret,28761)
    res_profiles = requests.get(profiles_requests_command)
    if res_profiles.status_code == 200:
        data = res_profiles.content
        data_split = data.split('\n')[:-1]
        data_split_ast = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in data_split]

        #take out characters from the beginning to have neat columns
        data_split_ast_pretty = [dict(zip(map(lambda x: x[4:], item.keys()), item.values())) for item in data_split_ast]


        #add current date
        current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        for item in data_split_ast_pretty:
            item['DateCreated'] = current_time


        random_sample = list(np.random.choice(data_split_ast_pretty,5))  
        print random_sample
        client.insert_rows_json(table = table, json_rows = random_sample)
    else:
        pass




run_api = python_operator.PythonOperator(task_id='call_api',
        python_callable=get_localytics_data)
```

I added the PYPI Packages of :

requests ===2.19.1

numpy ===1.12.0

google-cloud-bigquery ===1.4.0

I get the error of : **Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/composer_test_july30_v2.py] 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_table'**
in the Airflow UI Console.

All the code shown works locally but will not work using Cloud Composer.

Comment: What version of Cloud Composer are you using? You can get this from describing the environment.

Comment: If I go to the Environment Configuration the Image Version is : composer-0.5.1-airflow-1.9.0

Comment: Can you confirm the pypi installation succeeded? They should show on your pypi packages tab if it did.

Comment: Required libraries from the Python Package Index (PyPI)

Name
requests
numpy
google-cloud-bigquery
Version
===2.19.1
===1.12.0
===1.4.0

Comment: Yes the pypi installation succeeded.

Comment: I was able to bypass this issue by using googleapiclient.discovery developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/… , insertAll streaming API I was able to get the DAG to load properly in Airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got an out of date `google-cloud-bigquery` package, although it appears it should not be.

To check for sure, it will require SSH'ing into the Composer environment's Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters and running `pip freeze | grep bigquery` to find out what actual version is installed.

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list
2. Find the corresponding GKE cluster and click on it.
3. Click connect in the top.
4. Once in the console type `kubectl get pods`. A list of pods should appear.
5. Enter `kubectl exec -it <AIRFLOW_WORKER> /bin/bash` where  is once of the pods that start with airflow-worker-*.
6. Once inside the pod, type `pip freeze | grep bigquery`, and it should show the version of the module.

Comment: By using googleapiclient.discovery https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tabledata.html , insertAll streaming API I was able to get the DAG to load properly in Airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Google now publishes the Python packages/versions on the Composer images page https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions Just find the row for the version you are using, then expand the Packages column.

This is now by far the easiest way to get the package version because `pip freeze` on an Airflow worker now generates a list that cites the wheel file location rather than the version number. For example:

```
airflow@airflow-worker-*****:~$ pip freeze
absl-py @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-2.1.4/python3.8/absl_py-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
alembic @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-2.1.4/python3.8/alembic-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
amqp @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-2.1.4/python3.8/amqp-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
anyio @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-2.1.4/python3.8/anyio-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
etc....
```